# I am running a job in Jenkins but getting the below error using Custom Workspace:

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jobs

Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/kritikakesarwani/.jenkins/MavenArtifactId
[MavenArtifactId] $ /Users/kritikakesarwani/Documents/Selenium_Installation_eclipse/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn test -PRegression
/bin/sh: /Users/kritikakesarwani/Documents/Selenium_Installation_eclipse/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn: Operation not permitted
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE